# Akka remote actors with custom dispatcher

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, remote-actors

I'm experiencing difficulties with creating a remote actors with "UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
I have master machine from what actors are spawned, and slave on which actors will run.

master.conf:

```
#Akka remote configuration
akka {
  actor {
    stashed-dispatcher {
      mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
    }
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    deployment {
      "/*/RemoteChannelRoutingActor" {
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 2
        target.nodes = ["akka.tcp://MyRemoteSystem@192.168.12.108:2552"]
      }
    }
  }
  remote {
    log-sent-messages = on
    log-received-messages = on
    netty.tcp.port = 2554
    netty.tcp.hostname = "192.168.0.165"
  }
}
```

slave.conf:

```
#Akka remote configuration
akka {
  actor {
    stashed-dispatcher {
      mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
    }
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-received-messages = on
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "192.168.12.108"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
}
```

Remote actors is spawn by class ChronosScheduler:

```
class ChronosScheduler extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case ChannelIndex(channelIndex) =>
      context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props(new ChannelProcessingActor(channelIndex)).withDispatcher("akka.actor.stashed-dispatcher")), "RemoteChannelRoutingActor") ! "msg"
  }
}
```

and ChronosScheduler is spawn by object ChronosScheduler:

```
object ChronosScheduler {
  val system =
    ActorSystem("CreationSystem", ConfigFactory.load("master"))

  def sendSpawnCommand = {
    system.actorOf(Props[ChronosScheduler]) ! ChannelIndex(channelIndex)
  }

}
```

the error i have is this:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ConfigurationException: configuration problem while creating [akka://CreationSystem/RemoteChannelRoutingActor] with router dispatcher [akka.actor.default-dispatcher] and mailbox [akka.actor.default-mailbox] and routee dispatcher [akka.actor.default-dispatcher] and mailbox [akka.actor.default-mailbox]]]
Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Configuration missing for router [akka://CreationSystem/RemoteChannelRoutingActor] in 'akka.actor.deployment' section.
```

Can anyone give any tips on this error, please?
I think this happens because class ChronosScheduler doesent have access to object ChronosScheduler config.. but i cannot fix it anyhow.

***SOLUTION:***
  The problem i had was caused by manner in which i declared RemoteChannelRoutingActor in master.conf:

```
  " /*/RemoteChannelRoutingActor "
```

must be so:

```
  "  */RemoteChannelRoutingActor "
```

Comment: I might be wrong here, but the name you are giving to the `ChannelProcessingActor` when you create it inside the `ChronosScheduler` (value of `"/RemoteChannelRoutingActor"`) looks invalid to me.  I did not think that actor names could start with a leading slash.  You might want to remove that leading slash and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @cmbaxter sorry that was a typo. fixed. Ive tried different actor pathes such as /user/ChannelProcessingActor but it did not worked out